# how to make the image cover the complete section in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image section in my HTML like below

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url('ramoji_film_city/ramoji_weekend_dj_parties');?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/DJ_parties_web_banner.jpg" style="margin-top:-45px;"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is not covering the entire section. There is some white space around it. How can I get rid of it?

[image]
 how do i completely cover the image from left to right?

Comment: can you add a working example?

Comment: @cloned of my website?

Comment: i just want to cover the entire section with that image

Comment: of the example you posted above, if we execute your snippet we can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code, I hope it's working for you.

Thanks

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('ramoji_film_city/ramoji_weekend_dj_parties');?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/DJ_parties_web_banner.jpg" style="margin-top:-45px;" width="100%"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using bootstrap and `.row` class has 15px padding, that's why there is white space around your image. Add `.no-padding` class to `<div class="row">` DOM element and in your CSS set the following rule to overwrite Bootstrap rules:

```
.row.no-padding {
    padding: 0;
}




<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-padding">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('ramoji_film_city/ramoji_weekend_dj_parties');?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/DJ_parties_web_banner.jpg" style="margin-top:-45px;"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or with bootstrap you could just add `.p-0` class which is `padding: 0 !important;`